# How to add Button or jquery functionality inside odoo fields.Html field

Tags: javascript, jquery, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

I want to draw a custom table in **odoo form view**, So i am using fields.Html for it,

```
html_view = fields.Html('HTML View',compute="_create_html_view")
```

(This field is readonly mode in form view)

Now i wan to add button on each cell() of table, but field is in readonly mode it is now showing any button inside the table cells

SO i used link to instead of button, and link is working,

```
   def _create_html_view(self):
      view ='''<table style="width:100%" border="0"> 
<tr>
        <td style="background-color:white;width:15%;font-size:100%;text-align:center"><b> Column-1 </b></td>
        <td style="width:5%"></td>
        <td style="background-color:green;width:17%;font-size:100%;text-align:center"> <font color="white"><b>Column-2 </font> </b></td>
        <td style="width:5%"> </td>
        <td style="background-color:LimeGreen;width:18%;font-size:100%;text-align:center"> <font color="white"><b> Column-3 </font> </b></td>
        <td style="width:5%"></td>
        <td style="background-color:red;width:15%;font-size:100%;text-align:center"> <font color="white"><b>  Column-4 </font> </b></td>
        <td style="width:5%"></td>
        <td style="background-color:black;width:15%;font-size:100%;text-align:center"> <font color="white"><b>  Column -5 </font> </b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
        <td style="width:15%>  <button type="button">Click Me!</button> 
    </td>
        <td style="width:5%"></td>
        <td style="width:15%> <a style="background-color:powderblue;Bule:white;border-style: 2px solid;padding: 5px 11px;" href=" http://www.google.com " class="confirmation" >Click</a> """)</td>
        <td style="width:5%"> </td>
        <td style="width:18%;">  Column-3 </td>
        <td style="width:5%"></td>
        <td style="width:18%;">  Column-3 </td>
        <td style="width:5%"></td>
        <td style="width:18%;">  Column-3 </td>
</tr>
</table><p> <p>'''

      self.html_view=view (assign data to html field)
```

Now i want o show **conformation** on that link click so i add.

```
 <a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')" >click here</a>
```

But it is not working.

I try jquery to return conformation

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="confirmation" >click here</a>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
$( ".confirmation").click(function() {
    return confirm('Are you sure?');
});
```

**Anyone knows how to add jquery/javascript in fields.Html in odoo9/10**

or how to add button in side HTML-Field and conformation on that button

or how to add confirmation on link in HTML-Field.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: In preference menu of **res.users** there is field name '**signature**' which is html type field. In that field after drawing table we can add link in that particular cell and after saving that record if we click on that link it will redirect to particular page. Try on that and if it works try on your custom field

Comment: Thank you,  i am using also the same, i add the link in cell and onclicking that link it redirect to that link but 'i want a **conformation**' on that link before redirect.

Comment: Then you can add a popup via JS on that particular link's click there you can ask for confirmation.

Comment: i already try that, pass class on that link and try to catch click event using jquery for that class but i am not getting onclick event in Jquery on function script, also try to get event in other field/class to catch click event to check jquery is properly working,and it is working properly .

Comment: $( ".confirmation").click(function() {
     return confirm('Are you sure?');
    });

Comment: @KevalMehta hey bro i want to discuss with you on this issue can you give me any chat room link so we can discuss there. Thank you.